# consulta, mostrar todos los numeros si estan a nombre de un cliente

Tags: c++, dev-c++, pilas

estoy practicando pilas usando un caso de una empresa telefonica y queria saber como hacer que si un cliente tiene mas de 1 numero a su nombre los muestre todos los numeros pero no se como hacer, podrian ayudarme?

```
struct nodo{
    int numero;
    char nombre[50];
    nodo* siguiente;
} *primero;
 void buscarNodo(){
    nodo* actual = new nodo();
    actual = primero;
    string nodoBuscado ;
    bool encontrado = false;
    cout << " Ingrese el nombre del usuario a Buscar: ";
    cin >> nodoBuscado;
    if(primero!=NULL){
        while(actual!=NULL && encontrado != true){
            if( actual->nombre == nodoBuscado){
                cout << endl << " el cliente " << nodoBuscado << " Encontrado" << endl << endl;
                cout<<" su numero es: "<<actual->numero<<endl;
                encontrado = true;
            }
            actual = actual->siguiente;
        }
        if(encontrado==false){
            cout << endl << " Cliente no Encontrado" << endl << endl;
        }
    }else{
        cout << endl << " La Pila se encuentra vacia" << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Marco, antes de darte la solución creo que debería leer algo básico. Las pilas son un tipo particular de lista enlazada cuyas inserciones y extracciones se hacen por la cabeza. En el siguiente enlace [Introducción a la programación con C](http://repositori.uji.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10234/24306/s29.pdf) en el tema 4 tienes detalladas todas las operaciones.

Además, estás hablando de listas al estilo "C" porque C++ ya provee la STL Library donde resuelve esta situación con el contenedor Stack (basado en los contenedores básicos)  y con tipos templatizados. Es decir puedes crear tu lista con cualquier tipo de datos [C++11 STD Lib](http://www.cppstdlib.com/). En el tema 12 tienes la explicación [The C++ Standard Library A Reference Guide 2nd](https://www.mica.edu.vn/perso/Vu-Hai/EE3490/Ref/The%20C++Standard%20Library%20-%202nd%20Edition.pdf)

Si insistes en el estilo "C" puedes mirar el tema 11 del libro de Francisco Javier Ceballos [Curso C/C++](https://sites.google.com/site/elcepgeomet/c-c-curso-de-programacion-3a-edicion-cqlfqi) pero este lo hace con punteros a punteros y eso igual te lía. Comprender las pilas es importante si piensas en desarrollar por ejemplo videojuegos. La transición entre estados (play, pause por ejemplo) se hace con pilas.

En tu caso, sale de while a la primera ocurrencia, utiliza un for y recorre la lísta (pila) entera como en el método buscarNodo que te muestro

Te dejo una implementación completa por si te sirve de ayuda.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo{
    int numero;
    char nombre[50];
    struct Nodo* sig;
};

using TipoLista = struct Nodo*; // como typedef desde C++11

// Declaración de funciones
TipoLista lista_vacia();
int es_lista_vacia(TipoLista lista);
TipoLista inserta_por_cabeza(TipoLista lista, int valor, string cadena);
void muestra_lista(TipoLista lista);
void buscarNodo(TipoLista lista, string cadena); 
TipoLista libera_lista(TipoLista lista);  


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  TipoLista pila=lista_vacia();
  
  pila=inserta_por_cabeza(pila, 123, "Antonio");
  pila=inserta_por_cabeza(pila, 232, "Maite");
  pila=inserta_por_cabeza(pila, 222, "Carolina");
  pila=inserta_por_cabeza(pila, 456, "Antonio");
  pila=inserta_por_cabeza(pila, 342, "Maria");
  
  muestra_lista(pila);
  
  buscarNodo(pila, "Antonio");
  
  pila=libera_lista(pila);

}    /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */

// Definición de funciones
//

TipoLista lista_vacia() {
  return nullptr;
}

int es_lista_vacia(TipoLista lista) {
  return lista == nullptr; // 0 si es falso, distinto de 0 si es cierto
}

TipoLista inserta_por_cabeza(TipoLista lista, int valor, string cadena)
{
  struct Nodo* nuevo=new Nodo(); // creo un nodo nuevo en el Heap 

  nuevo->numero=valor;
  strcpy(nuevo->nombre, cadena.c_str()); // ojo a la incompatibilidad de tipos 
  nuevo->sig=lista;
  lista=nuevo;

  return lista;
}

void muestra_lista(TipoLista lista) {
  if (!es_lista_vacia(lista)) {
    struct Nodo* aux; // utilizo un puntero auxiliar para recorrer
    cout << "Mostrando lista ..." << endl;
    for (aux=lista; aux!=nullptr; aux=aux->sig) {
      cout << "[" << aux->numero << ", " << aux->nombre << "]" << endl;
    }
  }
  else 
    cout << "La lista está vacía, nada que mostrar" << endl;
}

void buscarNodo(TipoLista lista, string cadena) {
  if (!es_lista_vacia(lista)) {
    struct Nodo* aux;
    int cont=0;
    cout << "Buscando números de " << cadena << endl;
    for (aux=lista; aux!=nullptr; aux=aux->sig) {
      // antes de hacer comparaicones es conveniente convertir ambas cadenas a
      // mayúsculas o mínusculas
      if (aux->nombre == cadena) {  
        cout << "[" << aux->numero << ", " << aux->nombre << "]" << endl;
        cont++;
      }
    }
    if (cont==0)
      cout << "Cliente no encontrado" << endl;
  }
  else
    cout << "La lista está vacía, nada que buscar" << endl;
}

TipoLista libera_lista(TipoLista lista) {
  cout << "Liberando lista ..." << endl;
  struct Nodo *aux, *otroaux; // con el primero apunto al que borro, con el segundo al siguiente

  aux=lista;
  while (aux!=nullptr) {
    otroaux=aux->sig;
    delete aux;
    aux=otroaux;
  }
  lista=nullptr;
  cout << "Lista liberada, queda una lista vacía" << endl;
  return lista;
}
```

Comment: Se agradece el esfuerzo, pero esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. ¿ Has pasado por [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) ? Tal vez te convendría revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering). Un saludo.